# What exactly does up triangle \land symbol mean in the context of peak detection?

Tags: peak-detection

Folks, I'm reading this paper: [User Adaptive QRS Detection Based on One Target Clustering and Correlation Coefficient](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8584803), and have a question about notation.

In describing peak-detection, they use the following notation:
[image]

I understand this to mean something like for j=0 to 2: S(i-j) should be greater than S(i-j-1), and S(i+j+1) should be greater than S(i+J), where S is the signal.

But what is that up arrow symbol called? Is it just a logical and? As in this must be true for each of the j?

Thanks!

Comment: hm, I'm starting to follow the references given in the paragraph just above these two equations: What about [7] from the same authors?

Comment: I checked with the author and yes, it just means conjunction: logical and. So just as \sum_{j=0}^2{x_j} means x_0 + x_1 + x_2, \land_{j=0}^2{x_j} means x_0 \land x_1 \land x_2

Comment: that would make a great answer! It's totally OK to answer your own questions.